# If a record isn't found, make an attribute check return false instead of an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I want to check two things:

1. Has a user received a friend request? `current_user.friend_requests.find_by_receiver_id(user.id)`
2. And if so, have they accepted it?
   `current_user.friend_requests.find_by_receiver_id(user.id).accepted`

The problem is #2 raises an error if no request existed. How can I avoid this, and simply have it return false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can very easily return `nil` (which is falsy) if the record is not present, using `ActiveSupport`'s [`try`](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try) method:

```
current_user.friend_requests.find_by_receiver_id(user.id).try(:accepted)
```